# Unstack lubridate's interval class

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I am trying to transform a dataframe `df` consisting of a `value`-column, two date columns (`start` and `end`), and a interval-column (`duration`) into the long format by unnesting/unstacking the `duration` column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(value = letters[1:3], start = as_date(1:3), end = as_date(3:1)+3) %>% 
          mutate(duration = interval(start, end))
```

The expected outcome would a dataframe where `value`, `start`, and `end` are duplicated for each day as defined by `duration`. For instance, the value 'a' would appear 6 times each time on a different day (2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th January 1970).

I tried to use the `unnest` function from the `tidyr` package but nothing happened.

```
tidyr::unnest(df, duration)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't unstack a column of intervals and expect it to generate all dates in between, but by using `seq` you can generate them yourself. Try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  summarise(
    value, dates = seq(start, end, by = 1)
  )
```

```
#> # A tibble: 12 x 2
#>    value dates     
#>    <chr> <date>    
#>  1 a     1970-01-02
#>  2 a     1970-01-03
#>  3 a     1970-01-04
#>  4 a     1970-01-05
#>  5 a     1970-01-06
#>  6 a     1970-01-07
#>  7 b     1970-01-03
#>  8 b     1970-01-04
#>  9 b     1970-01-05
#> 10 b     1970-01-06
#> 11 c     1970-01-04
#> 12 c     1970-01-05
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following solution. Since we are going to create duplicate rows we can wrap the operation in a list and then use `unnest_longer`. `purrr` package functions have always been my first choice but you can also use this as an alternative.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)


df %>% 
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(date = list(start + 0:(duration/ddays(1)))) %>%
  unnest_longer(date) %>%
  select(-duration)


# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   value [3]
   value start      end        date      
   <chr> <date>     <date>     <date>    
 1 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-02
 2 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-03
 3 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-04
 4 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-05
 5 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-06
 6 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-07
 7 b     1970-01-03 1970-01-06 1970-01-03
 8 b     1970-01-03 1970-01-06 1970-01-04
 9 b     1970-01-03 1970-01-06 1970-01-05
10 b     1970-01-03 1970-01-06 1970-01-06
11 c     1970-01-04 1970-01-05 1970-01-04
12 c     1970-01-04 1970-01-05 1970-01-05
```

Comment: Thanks, Anoushiravan. I am getting an weird error `do not know how to convert 'value' to class “Date”`.

Comment: It's strange. I checked it again and I got the same result. Mind updating your packages cause I just updated my whole packages and there have been occasions that OP could not get the result I did due to using older packages. But it's weird because nothing specific happens in this solution.

Comment: That's probably it. I will try again later!

Comment: OK then let me know.

Comment: Ok my pleasure. Have you realized which package solved your error?

Comment: Unfortunately, I updated them all at once

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `interval` is helping here - `seq.Date` might be better...

```
library(purrr) #as well as those you have

df <- data.frame(value = letters[1:3], start = as_date(1:3), end = as_date(3:1)+3) %>% 
   mutate(day = map2(start, end, seq.Date, by = "day")) %>% 
   unnest(day)

df
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   value start      end        day       
   <chr> <date>     <date>     <date>    
 1 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-02
 2 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-03
 3 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-04
 4 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-05
 5 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-06
 6 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-07
 7 b     1970-01-03 1970-01-06 1970-01-03
 8 b     1970-01-03 1970-01-06 1970-01-04
 9 b     1970-01-03 1970-01-06 1970-01-05
10 b     1970-01-03 1970-01-06 1970-01-06
11 c     1970-01-04 1970-01-05 1970-01-04
12 c     1970-01-04 1970-01-05 1970-01-05
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew, also a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

To extract the start and end date from interval you can use `int_start` and `int_end`, create a sequence of dates with `map2` and `unnest`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(date = map2(int_start(duration), int_end(duration), 
                ~seq(as.Date(.x), as.Date(.y), by = 'day'))) %>%
  #This will also work but would return date of class POSIXct
  #mutate(date = map2(int_start(duration), int_end(duration),seq,by = 'day')) %>%
  unnest(date) %>%
  select(-duration)

#    value start      end        date      
#   <chr> <date>     <date>     <date>    
# 1 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-02
# 2 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-03
# 3 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-04
# 4 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-05
# 5 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-06
# 6 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-07
# 7 b     1970-01-03 1970-01-06 1970-01-03
# 8 b     1970-01-03 1970-01-06 1970-01-04
# 9 b     1970-01-03 1970-01-06 1970-01-05
#10 b     1970-01-03 1970-01-06 1970-01-06
#11 c     1970-01-04 1970-01-05 1970-01-04
#12 c     1970-01-04 1970-01-05 1970-01-05
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I like the solution and it works perfectly (the accepted answer is a little less typing)

Answer (score 2):

with `uncount`

```
df %>% uncount(as.integer(duration/(24*60*60)) +1) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(date = row_number() -1 + start)

# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   value [3]
   value start      end        duration                       date      
   <chr> <date>     <date>     <Interval>                     <date>    
 1 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-02 UTC--1970-01-07 UTC 1970-01-02
 2 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-02 UTC--1970-01-07 UTC 1970-01-03
 3 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-02 UTC--1970-01-07 UTC 1970-01-04
 4 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-02 UTC--1970-01-07 UTC 1970-01-05
 5 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-02 UTC--1970-01-07 UTC 1970-01-06
 6 a     1970-01-02 1970-01-07 1970-01-02 UTC--1970-01-07 UTC 1970-01-07
 7 b     1970-01-03 1970-01-06 1970-01-03 UTC--1970-01-06 UTC 1970-01-03
 8 b     1970-01-03 1970-01-06 1970-01-03 UTC--1970-01-06 UTC 1970-01-04
 9 b     1970-01-03 1970-01-06 1970-01-03 UTC--1970-01-06 UTC 1970-01-05
10 b     1970-01-03 1970-01-06 1970-01-03 UTC--1970-01-06 UTC 1970-01-06
11 c     1970-01-04 1970-01-05 1970-01-04 UTC--1970-01-05 UTC 1970-01-04
12 c     1970-01-04 1970-01-05 1970-01-04 UTC--1970-01-05 UTC 1970-01-05
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(date = seq(start, end, by = 1)), by = .(value)]
# value       date
# 1:     a 1970-01-02
# 2:     a 1970-01-03
# 3:     a 1970-01-04
# 4:     a 1970-01-05
# 5:     a 1970-01-06
# 6:     a 1970-01-07
# 7:     b 1970-01-03
# 8:     b 1970-01-04
# 9:     b 1970-01-05
#10:     b 1970-01-06
#11:     c 1970-01-04
#12:     c 1970-01-05
```